# How can I get the sum of array values that match each other?

Tags: php, arrays

For particular reasons, I won't be doing this in a SQL query even though it seems that would make sense. I would like to manipulate this data in PHP.

I am outputting results using PHP to a CSV file.  Those CSV results look like this:

```
Event Date          Client      Event Type      Location        Player      Pay      Total
2020/05/30 7:00 PM  Erin        Public Event    Effingham       Davy T      10
2020/05/01 9:00 PM  Mike        Fundraiser      Lakewood        Greg P      100
2020/06/13 1:30 AM  Jeff        Wedding         Lakewood        Greg P      60
2020/05/30 7:00 PM  Erin        Public Event    Effingham       Katrina N   0
2020/05/01 9:00 PM  Mike        Fundraiser      Lakewood        Michael S   400
2020/06/12 1:30 AM  Jeff        Wedding         Lakewood        Michael S   50
2020/06/13 1:30 AM  Jeff        Wedding         Lakewood        Michael S   61
2020/03/14 5:00 PM  Kimberly    Corporate       Aurora          Robert D    12.5
2020/05/01 9:00 PM  Mike        Fundraiser      Lakewood        Robert D    450
2020/05/30 7:00 PM  Erin        Public Event    Effingham       Robert D    0
2020/06/12 1:30 AM  Jeff        Wedding         Lakewood        Robert D    51
```

I want to sum the values where the names match, so that it would look like this:

```
Event Date          Client      Event Type      Location        Player      Pay      Total
2020/05/30 7:00 PM  Erin        Public Event    Effingham       Davy T      10       10
2020/05/01 9:00 PM  Mike        Fundraiser      Lakewood        Greg P      100      160
2020/06/13 1:30 AM  Jeff        Wedding         Lakewood        Greg P      60       160
2020/05/30 7:00 PM  Erin        Public Event    Effingham       Katrina N   0        0
2020/05/01 9:00 PM  Mike        Fundraiser      Lakewood        Michael S   400      511
2020/06/12 1:30 AM  Jeff        Wedding         Lakewood        Michael S   50       511
2020/06/13 1:30 AM  Jeff        Wedding         Lakewood        Michael S   61       511 
2020/03/14 5:00 PM  Kimberly    Corporate       Aurora          Robert D    12.5     513.5
2020/05/01 9:00 PM  Mike        Fundraiser      Lakewood        Robert D    450      513.5
2020/05/30 7:00 PM  Erin        Public Event    Effingham       Robert D    0        513.5
2020/06/12 1:30 AM  Jeff        Wedding         Lakewood        Robert D    51       513.5
```

My current PHP code for outputting the query is:

```
$csv_output = '"'.implode('","',array_keys($results[0])).'",Total'."\n";;


  foreach ($results as $row) {
    print_r($row);
    $csv_output .= '"'.implode('","',$row).'",'."\n";
  }
```

Here is an example of the array output by adding print_r into the foreach loop:

```
Array
(
    [Event Date] => 2020/02/21 05:00 PM
    [Client] => Jeff
    [Event Type] => Wedding
    [Location] => Lakewood
    [Player] => Greg P
    [Pay] => 60
)
Array
(
    [Event Date] => 2020/05/30 07:00 PM
    [Client] => Erin
    [Event Type] => Public Event
    [Location] => Effingham
    [Player] => Davy
    [Pay] => 10
)
Array
(
    [Event Date] => 2020/05/01 09:00 PM
    [Client] => Mike
    [Event Type] => Fundraiser
    [Location] => Lakewood
    [Player] => Greg
    [Pay] => 100
)
```

How can I gather the sum amount of 'Pay' and put that into the total fields where the array values match each other as shown in the desired csv output above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must iterate over array two times. First for counting sums of pays, and second to create new element of array.

```
$players = [
    [
        'Player' => 'Greg P',
        'Pay' => 60
    ],
    [
        'Player' => 'Greg P',
        'Pay' => 10
    ],
    [
        'Player' => 'Davy',
        'Pay' => 60
    ]
];

$pays = [];

foreach ($players as $player) {
    $pays[$player['Player']] = ($pays[$player['Player']] ?? 0) + $player['Pay'];
}

foreach (array_keys($players) as $playerKey) {
    $players[$playerKey]['Total'] = $pays[$players[$playerKey]['Player']];
}
```

Output for my example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Player] => Greg P
            [Pay] => 60
            [Total] => 70
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Player] => Greg P
            [Pay] => 10
            [Total] => 70
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Player] => Davy
            [Pay] => 60
            [Total] => 60
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate sum for each client using array_walk and second array as [Client => Sum]

```
<?php

$array = [
    [
        'Client' => 'x',
        'Pay' => 1
    ],
    [
        'Client' => 'y',
        'Pay' => 1
    ],
    [
        'Client' => 'x',
        'Pay' => 5
    ]
];

$tempValues = [];

array_walk($array, function($row) use (&$tempValues) {
    if (!isset($tempValues[$row['Client']])) {
        $tempValues[$row['Client']] = 0;
    }
    $tempValues[$row['Client']] += $row['Pay'];
});
```

this will give you:

```
array(2) {
  ["x"]=>
  int(6)
  ["y"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

and then include `$tempValues[$row['Client']]` to your csv output.